# Photographing Sea Turtles hatching on the beach

Tags: canon, wildlife

I'm going to shoot some turtles and watch their walk to the water. I have a Canon t5i rebel and I don't know which settings to use for this particular shot.

Which settings should I use to get sharp pictures?

Should I use all servo or not while focusing?

Should I use AV or shutter speed priority?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sea turtles normally hatch at night. So I'd plan to visit during a full moon, if you can. That way you will have some natural light to work with. I'd recommend using the slowest shutter speed you can that still gives you a blur free shot, so use Shutter Priority (TV on Canons). Newborn turtles generally move in bursts, so focus your shooting on the ones resting between sprints to the sea. That way you can drop your shutter speed to, say, the 1/20th range and still get a crisp shot that is well exposed during a full moon.

If you are doing this at sunrise, I'd recommend using aperture priority (AV). If you want a lot of detail, a larger f/stop will get you that (say f/12 or f/16). If f/12 is too slow, switch back to shutter priority (TV) and shoot from there until the sun comes up enough for you to move over to aperture priority.

I know most sea turtles are dark in color and most beaches have white to grey sand so you might end up with the turtle underexposed or the sand overexposed. To correct this you can shoot RAW and then, in an editing program such as Lightroom, correct the exposure. Or you can use the Canon's built-in HDR setting to help properly expose your shots. Another option would be to set your metering mode to either point or center weighted. You can also use exposure compensation on your camera to help correct the problem.

If your autofocus has enough light to actually focus without much trouble, use it otherwise, use the manual focus.

Don't use your flash and don't use a flashlight to illuminate them, bright lights will confuse them and make their trek to the sea all that harder.

Comment: Hey chris im not gonna do it at night. It's daytime just early in the morning since we are going to free them. Its like an association that is in charge to protect this specific turtles ( el

Comment: @Jorgeluis See my edited post, and good luck in your endeavor!

Comment: Also, turtles tend to hatch at the full moon, so if you want to see them at all, it's more than likely going to be a full moon anyway.

Comment: @J... Actually, lunar phase has [very little measurable significance](http://www.coastalbiology.org/incoming/2014/7/16/the-moon-and-sea-turtles) [in new sea turtle emergence](http://www.seaturtle.org/mtn/archives/mtn127/mtn127p12.shtml?nocount)

Comment: @ChrisStillwell Well there's that, then.  I guess I mis-remembered David Attenborough... pulled out my Blue Planet DVDs just to be sure, haha.  Seems they nest around the first and last quarter of the moon in November but hatching happens whenever.

Comment: Btw guys two questions about my camera. Sometimes when i shoot mostly at dark after i take the shot it tames a while to process and it says busy and when i see its blurry i adjust the settings but stills nothing. And the other one. In the menu my AF method is FlexiZone--multi is that good for starting as me?

Comment: @Jorgeluis The longer your shutter speed, the longer the processing time is to store the image.  You really start to notice this with really long exposures (>1s).  If that's the case then you're just not getting enough light and the camera is resorting to using a shutter speed that is much too long. For night you'll probably want as fast a lens as you can get your hands on (F/2.8 is good, F/1.8 or F/1.4 is better). Put your ISO up as high as you can tolerate for quality and that's about all you can do.  Keep in mind that focus becomes much more important at wide apertures also as you lose DoF.

Comment: Thanks for that. Btw forget to tell to this specific moment should i use all servo or all focus?

Comment: FlexiZone-multi is only available when shooting in Live View. Unless your camera is mounted on a tripod you should not be using LV in low light. Holding the camera out on front of you to see the rear LCD screen makes the camera far less stable than holding it to your face and looking through the viewfinder.